# Incorrect totalElements and totalPages values for Spring Page

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I have 21 rows in a database and I am using Spring's Page to get them.

If I specify a page size less than 22, it will show totalElements: 3864 and totalPages is also wrong. What could be wrong?

Example:
`GET myurl.com/foo?size=5`

yields a result like this

```
{
   
        "content": [
            {
               { "pretend_that": "there are five elements here" }
            }
        ],
        "pageable": {
            "sort": {
                "empty": true,
                "sorted": false,
                "unsorted": true
            },
            "offset": 0,
            "pageNumber": 0,
            "pageSize": 5,
            "paged": true,
            "unpaged": false
        },
        "last": false,
        "totalPages": 773,
        "totalElements": 3864,
        "size": 5,
        "number": 0,
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "first": true,
        "numberOfElements": 5,
        "empty": false
}
```

Example 2:

```
GET myurl.com/foo?size=50
```

yields a result like this

```
{
    
        "content": [
            {
                { "pretend_that": "there are 21 elements here" }
            }
        ],
        "pageable": {
            "sort": {
                "empty": true,
                "sorted": false,
                "unsorted": true
            },
            "offset": 0,
            "pageNumber": 0,
            "pageSize": 50,
            "paged": true,
            "unpaged": false
        },
        "last": true,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "totalElements": 21,
        "size": 50,
        "number": 0,
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "first": true,
        "numberOfElements": 21,
        "empty": false
    
}
```

P.S. if I get the final page, it shows the page and elements count correctly.

I have tried changing Spring Boot versions and that hasn't helped.